# Team Site: If you delete owners group from site coll admins you cannot get it back

Tags: site-collection, office-365-groups

I am in this situation where the owners group has been deleted from site collection owners and when i try to put it back I only get the members group available.

Can someone help? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this can be done

If you navigate to https://(give your site URL)/_layouts/permsetup.aspx, you'll be taken to the Group Set-Up screen.

In the Owners section, use an existing group and see if you can find the Team Site Owners group in there. If so, select it and press OK. This should restore the group.

What's happened is that the site has removed the user group but it has't been deleted via the root site.

I also see O365 tag so do check this [link here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group?view=o365-worldwide)

Hope that helps,

Comment: the group set up screen shows the 3 groups fine, the owners have not been put back in site collection admin. I am talking about a modern Team site/ o365 group site and not the classic sharepoint site

Comment: Have you checked this link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/restore-deleted-group?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a new owners group, and add the users back into it.  You will need to be a Site Collection Admin to do this though.